# php datetime custom formatting

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to use

```
format("m/d/y \a\\t h:ia T");
```

to get

```
05/14/15 at 04:22am MDT
```

which used to work but now all of a sudden I'm getting

```
Exception: DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (05/14/15 at 04:22am MDT) at position 9 (a): The timezone could not be found in the database in some/folders/and.files on line x
```

So my work around for now is taking the "at" out

```
format('m/d/y h:ia T');
```

I've found I can leave the `\a` in with no problem but the `\a\\t` causes the error. Any on how to get past this?

**edit

The timestamp being passed in is generated by mysql

```
2015-05-14 10:22:41
```

**edit

This accepted answer didn't actually solve the problem for me. I am certain the issue is unique to my server / application so once I figure it out on my own I'll post back here as to avoid any further downvotes.

Comment: The date you are passing is invalid. It has nothing to do with how you are trying to format it. If you are trying to consume that date either use a standard format or use `createFromFormat()`;

Comment: Why do you have to use `\a\\t` for `at`? Why not just `\at` or `\a\t`?

Comment: Please show your **full** and **real** code which you use to create this error.

Comment: @tuananh I was getting a tab character for \t so I changed it to \\t. I guessing that has to do with double quotes vs single quotes hence the change.

Comment: @JohnConde The timestamp is coming from a MySQL server so it's valid. And I wish more people gave criticism with their downvote so as odd as it sounds, thanks for that.

Comment: @Jackson Believe it or not it wasn't me who downvoted.

Comment: @JohnConde well then +1 for criticism without the downvote.

Comment: "This accepted answer didn't actually solve the problem for me". In which case it should not be the accepted answer. Don't accept an answer unless it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with a LOT of data and a LOT of files (classes) to get this thing working so I couldn't paste all my code in here or else no one would look at this question. **So here's the skinny on what was actually happening:**

Inside of a loop my time value was getting replaced with the formatted value and then getting caught up in the same loop, hence why I was getting that error and everything thought I was getting time with an incorrect value because ultimately I was (the first time it was okay but not on the re-run).

## resolution

When in doubt, print out the time *value* going INTO your `DateTime->format` and you may be surprised that it's not what you think it is.